# Thermodynamics of harmonic oscillators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I have N harmonic oscillators in thermal equilibrium at temperature $T$,

$$ E(n_{1},...,n_{N})= \hbar \omega \sum_{i=1}^{N}(n_{i} + \frac{1}{2})$$

And I calculated partition function like this

$$Z = \hbar \omega \sum_{i=1}^{N} e^{-\beta E} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\hbar \omega}{k_{B}T}} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(e^{-\frac{\hbar \omega}{k_{B}T}}\right)^{n_{i}} $$

is it right?

How to calculate free energy $F$ (Helmholtz free energy) and average energy $\left<E\right>$?

Comment: You need to sum over each of the integers $n_i$ from $n_i=1$ to $n_i=\infty$ as well the $i$'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the oscillators are independent of each other.
$$Z_N=(Z_1)^N$$

where $Z_1$ is the partition function of one harmonics oscillator.
$$Z_1=\sum_n e^{-\beta\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar \omega}$$
Once you have found $Z_N$. You can use
$$F=e^{-\beta Z}$$
$$E=-\frac{d\ln Z}{d\beta}$$